# Unable to use graphics after calling delegate

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, graphics, delegates, callback

I am working on a feature on a large program. The feature requires a call to something that can be computationally intensive, and can take a long time. The result of the calculations - that are triggered from a menu item - will add something to the current drawing.

There are lots of other options that change the current drawing. I am not discussing them here. Suffice to say, I would like for the "processing" that I created to be asynchronous, so that the user will not have to stare for 5 minutes at a non-responsive screen thinking that the program is broken, but be able to click other places...

So: the processing will be asynchronous, but at the end, I will have to draw the result.

The problem: I can't draw.

If I run my code, without asynchronous calling, everything works perfectly, of course. But if I call processing on BeginInvoke, there are a few problems:

1) The method I call returns immediately, so in the main thread, if I place a call to "draw", the results are not generated yet

2) If I try to put the draw after the EndInvoke, it is on the wrong thread, so every single item inside myGraphics says "Parameter is not valid".

3) Even if I keep the call right after BeginInvoke (and re-call it somehow), myGraphics still seems to have gone to a different thread, I seem to have wrong information in it.

For best results, I should be able to return from the threads, close them somehow, after EndInvoke... I just don't know how.

The following code is a fragment, meant to show the call to "processing", and then the "draw". (Edit: I have removed more from the code so people will not try to type it in and think that my problem is basic compilation errors, like a typo or something)

```
Public Sub mine(ByVal myGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics)
  a_call()
 ' use results from the finished call to process graphics
  my_draw(myGraphics)
 ' if I add my_draw here, previous call only had BeginInvoke... more complicated to prevent my_draw... 
 ' but it is not horrible to have first draw empty, and later draw correctly (if there is a way to trigger it - which I don't really have)
 ' The bigger problem is, myGraphics becomes defective (its VisibleClipbounds change, most points are not drawn anymore - or it becomes undefined)
 ' I don't understand why myGraphics changes or how to fix it
end sub

Public Sub a_call()      
  Dim c As New ADelegate(AddressOf A)    ' which is the processing call
  c.BeginInvoke(cb, Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub A_Callback(ByVal ia As IAsyncResult)      
  ...EndInvoke(ia)
  A_Finish()
End Sub
Private Sub A_Finish()
  If Me.InvokeRequired Then
     Invoke(New ADelegate(AddressOf A_Finish))
  Else
   ' call my_draw because I should be done with the Invoke ?
   ' If I add my_draw here, it is undefined
End Sub
```

When I said that myGraphics gets modified... I really can't see what can change it...

I have been fighting with understanding threading, and delegates... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can see that someone downvoted my question, and voted to close it, with no comment - helpful or not. I have been fighting this issue for 2 days, so if you think that I have put insufficient effort, or that there are similar questions out there, please give me a hint - direct me to a similar issue. Any constructive help is appreciated.

Comment: what compile options are you using? Option Explicit on? I get 6 Errors from this code with option Explicit on.

Comment: If the processing done by `Y()` must be compleated before the draw what advantages do you gain by calling it asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that System.Drawing.Graphics cannot be "owned" by any function, therefore it doesn't make sense to be passed around like a ball.

Since it belongs to a UI class - and gets created properly with Paint events - my solution was to disconnect the drawing process from the calculation process.

Instead of waiting for calculations to complete before drawing, I did draw separately (triggered by paint events) when I had fresh information to draw, and I calculated asynchronously - with complete disregard of anything happening in the UI.